# The capture filters in "Wireshark - Capture Filters" are not enforced by Wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireshark

The "Wireshark - Capture Filters" shows a list of filters by default, but none of these seems to be enforced.

In particular, the "No ARP and no DNS" filter should remove DNS, but as can be seen from the screenshot below, this is not the case:

[image]

So, why are these filters listed, if they have no affect? And how to I actually apply capture filters?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the Capture Filter - it is a list of common cap. filters you can use when capturing.
However, you need to **specify** which cap. filter you are using, and you can only use one.
You can have a list of hundreds, thousands or more capture filter and use only one at a time.